# How to add podcasts manually to the new Podcasts.app on macOS Catalina

Tags: itunes, podcasts, catalina

I'm on macOS Catalina (10.15 Beta (19A471t)), and I'm trying to add manually downloaded podcasts that I copied from an iTunes library to the new Podcasts.app.

I tried to simply drag the files into the `~/Library/GroupContainers/243LU875E5.groups.com.apple.podcasts` folder (- location of all the downloaded podcasts), but after that, the files still aren't appearing in the app.

I can see that the downloaded files in the mentioned podcasts folder have special file names (e.g. `7BE50452-8412-4232-B384-D9E1B94813ED.mp3`).

Downloading again the files within the Podcasts.app, is not always a solution, As @Dillon pointed out in the comments.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 12):

From what I found there is no way to add an audio file into Podcast application: as of macOS Catalina, it supports only subscribing to RSS feeds. The only way built-in way to listen to the separate podcast episode is to find it via application search and add it separately.

However, I found out that you can listen to any audio files including MP3 the same way you did in Podcasts in **Books** application by adding them there via `File` -> `Add to Library...` and then syncing them to iPhone.

Comment: "to find it via application search and add it separately" - can you please explain what you mean?. Thanks for the tip with the books.app!

Comment: I mean that you can find any existing podcast/episode in Podcasts app via search, and push a plus sign next to it to add it to your podcasts Library. You don't need to subscribe to the whole podcast in order to listen to a single episode of it.

Comment: O.K, so you say that there is **no way** to manually add to the podcast.app an episode that is already on my computer (in some regular folder).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Books.app is the closest replacement we got for this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any source for that?

Comment: I couldn't find any proofs of things being another way around on the internet and I've checked everything I could in the Podcasts app. There _might_ be some technical workaround to that (either generating your own feed locally or injecting podcast information in the application somehow, can't think of anything else), but I believe that using Books app is the far simpler answer to this problem.

Comment: The Apple Books app is a nice way to listen to long audio lectures, as it saves the spot you're at in the lecture, and also has a nice 15-second rewind button. But it requires syncing these files directly between Mac and iPhone. iCloud is supposed to free people from have to do direct syncs. That way, it's easy to listen on a different device as well. Is there an iCloud or 3rd party cloud solution that comes with desktop and mobile apps?

Comment: @jacob I think [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313321/107414) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov - It doesn't appear that it's supported for audiobooks:
https://discussions.apple.com/content/attachment/824676040
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/sync-audiobooks-to-your-device-mchlf764c5a4/mac

Comment: What's mad is that is that all the previously added mp3 episodes (before switching to Catalina) still show in my podcast app, you just can't add new ones.