# Is there a good app/service for listening to private audio files?

Tags: macos, ios, audio, software-recommendation, mediaplayer

I have a lot of audio lecture mp3 files. They tend to run 30-90 minutes long. I've uploaded many of them to Google Play Music, and listen to them on my Mac and iPhone using the Google Play Music web site or app.

It works okay, but the main problem is it doesn't have 15-second rewind/forward buttons in case I want to hear something again. Is there an app that would be better for that, particularly that can use iCloud or some cloud service that can store all these files to make syncing easier?

It seems that Apple Music / iTunes might work okay for listening on iPad, since the Apple Music iPad app has a 15-second rewind button, but the iPhone and Mac apps do not have this button. The Podcasts app functionality works nice, but I don't think it supports private uploads.

Comment: It's a problem if you use Catalina though: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366075/how-to-add-podcasts-manually-to-the-new-podcasts-app-on-macos-catalina

Comment: There are podcast players which allow manual upload of audio files

Comment: Thanks. Using the Apple Books app to listen to these audio lectures solves the problem of rewind, as well as saves the spot you're at in the lecture. But it requires syncing directly between Mac and iPhone. iCloud is supposed to free people from have to do direct syncs. Is there an iCloud or 3rd party cloud solution that comes with desktop and mobile apps?